# can i pass my php code to twig code of timber

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

I would like to know if I can convert any types of PHP code to twig, what I want to know is, for example, whether I can pass the code.

```
<?php
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'in'):?
```

to

```
{{ lang.en }}
```

Is there a way to add any PHP code and turn it into a twig and recognize it?

I use the Timber template for WordPress.

Comment: You can add any custom function/filter to timber. See [here](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/#adding-functionality-to-twig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good way to pass your functions (more correctly, register the function to Twig).

## Using Timber Hook: `timber/twig`

There is a class in filter hook `timber/twig` could help us pass functions to Twig. It calls `Timber\Twig_Function`.

```
new Timber\Twig_Function(
    'function_name_that_will_be_called_in_Twig',
    'function_name_in_php'
);

// OR
new Timber\Twig_Function(
    'function_name_that_will_be_called_in_Twig',
    function( $input ) {
        // anonymous function is ok too.
    }
);
```

**functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', 'add_to_twig' );

function hello_in_php( $name = 'world' ) {
    $hello = 'Hello ';
    $hello .= $name;

    return $hello;
}

function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $func = new Timber\Twig_Function('hello', 'hello_in_php');
    $filter = new Timber\Twig_Function('introduce', function( $name ) {
        return "I'm ${name}!";
    });

    $twig->addFunction($func); //Registering a pre-defined function
    $twig->addFunction($filter); //Registering a filter function

    return $twig;
}
```

**index.twig**:

```
<p id='a'>{{ hello() }}</p>
<p id='b'>{{ hello('who?') }}</p>
<p id='c'>{{ "Batman"|introduce }}</p>
```

**Result is**:

```
<p id='a'>Hello World</p>
<p id='b'>Hello who?</p>
<p id='c'>I'm Batman!</p>
```

Source: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/#adding-functionality-to-twig

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this comparison ?

```
{% if constant('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') == 'en' %}
    {# your output here #}
{% endif %}
```