# Advanced Custom Fields, Timber and retrieving user's name

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber, gantry-framework

I’m trying to find a way to display the name of each user below the post, they will be listed as the author and contributors, each name will be linked to their profile, and in their profile there are also fields (from ultimate member plugin) which are their crypto wallets public addresses, that’s a way they can use to receive cryptocurrency donations for their contributions to the blog. I summarized everything in the following sketch:

[Sketch (Or screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKkPz.png)

The problem is that I’m using Gantry5 framework and only recently I found out that Gantry uses a programming language of its own, called Timber, this also brings back some memories about Final Fantasy XVIII, well, anyway, the problem I’m facing here is that I’m not being able to retrieve the user’s name.

The file’s name is “content-single.html.twig”, located in the following structure “themes/g5_helium/views/partials/”. Using Gantry5 Helium Theme.
But since I’ve created a custom override, it’s located at:
“themes/g5_helium/custom/views/partials/”

I’m editing the area after this part:

```
{# Begin Page Content #}
                {{ post.paged_content|raw }}

                {{ function('wp_link_pages', {'before': '<div class="page-links" itemprop="pagination"><ul class="pagination-list">', 'after': '</ul></div>', 'link_before': '<span class="page-number page-numbers">', 'link_after': '</span>', 'echo': 0}) }}
                {# End Page Content #}
```

And this is what I’ve used after a person in Gantry community helped me:

```
{% set post_id = function('get_the_ID') %}
{% set post = wordpress.call('Timber::get_post', post_id) %}
{{ post.meta('autor')|raw }}                
{{ post.meta('narrador')|raw }}
```

The problem is that whether I set the data format for user array or user object, I’m getting “Array” as output. Only if I set User ID I get the ID number, but that’s not what I need, what I need is to display the name of the user, and display it linked to their profile, just like it’s shown in the sketch. When I check the timber docs, it doesn’t seem to have much info on ACF there. If it was php only, it would be easy for me to find a workaround, but I’m totally lost because it’s timber.

Someone helped me with the following:

> Check out this documentation for Timber / ACF integrations:
>
> https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/
>
> Additionally the Timber/Post has a method called author:
>
> https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#author
>
> See below for example, which has a property post.author.ID
>
> ```
>   <a href="{{post.author.link}}">{{post.author.name}}</a>
> ```
>
> Something i always find useful is `{{ dump( post ) }}`, just remember
> to have WP_DEBUG enabled.
>
> Are you assigning an author via a custom field? Then you can try using `{{ post.get_field(" field_name") }}` and assiging that to a variable such
> as `{% set author = post.get_field(" field_name") %} then {{ dump() }}` the output to see what data is being returned.
>
> You need to dump the variable so it should be {% set author =
> post.get_field("autor") %} then {{ dump(author) }}, make use WP_DEBUG
> is enabled in your wp-config
>
> Otherwise make sure that you are adding a Post\Timber object to
> $context instead of WP_Post.

I did what was said and this is the result I received in the output:

`then array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> int(1) ["user_firstname"]=> string(7) "John" ["user_lastname"]=> string(5) "Doe" ["nickname"]=> string(4) "john" ["user_nicename"]=> string(13) "johndoe" ["display_name"]=> string(13) "John Doe" ["user_email"]=> string(23) "contact@site.com" ["user_url"]=> string(23) "https://siteDOTcom" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2019-03-12 03:53:10" ["user_description"]=> string(0) "" ["user_avatar"]=> string(472) "John Doe" } }`

But now I don't know how to use it with Timber, since Timber doesn's accept PHP.

This is another way that I'm trying to use to work around this issue, but with no success:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478272/11457250

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Timber uses a templating language called twig, to output a value use double curly brackets. Once you have set the variable author you can access they array values my afixing the key to the variable ie. `{{ author.user_firstname }}`

Comment: I first tried to test using your code, but it didn't work:
`{% set post_id = function('get_the_ID') %}
{% set post = wordpress.call('Timber::get_post', post_id) %}
{{ author.user_firstname }}`

Comment: you can access the author for example by <a href="{{post.author.link}}">{{post.author.name}}</a>, see documentation here https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#author

Comment: Ideally though you would add the Timber\Post object to context in your php file instead of assigning it in the template

Comment: That's for custom fields. I may try `{{ post.get_field(" field_name") }}` But then I'd need to specify the arrays part, which is what I'm not being able to do. I already used `{% set author = post.get_field(" field_name") %} then {{ dump() }}` to dump the values and they are specified inside the question.